# Getting coordinates through comparing .pgm files using opencv

Tags: ros, navigation, opencv, coordinate-system, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1 - Generated the .pgm files through gmapping using LIDAR data.

-- One with partial map

-- One with map of the whole area

Trying to:

2 - Use opencv to compare the maps

3 - To get the coordinates of the lidar at the partial map

-- For pinpointing this lidar in the full map

Above is the brief summary of the problem encountered. Anyone may have any advice or a direct solution.

Please and Thank You viewers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227725/getting-coordinates-through-comparing-.pgm-files-using-opencv/) by [Avonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/26092/avonic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A variant of what you describe is implemented in the [hector_mapstitch](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/mapstitch/tree/hector_mapstitch) package. It can be used to align two maps with each other. When both robots run a SLAM system, their relative poses can be computed from the transform between the two maps and their location in their respective maps.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/26092/avonic/) on 2016-03-01**:
I am getting quite confuse with the ros_mapstitch function. Can you please advice me on that thank you.